# Check a radio button from data saved in localstorage in a specific form, with a specific name and value

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<form class="questionnaire" name="X">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1. text</td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" >Yes     </label><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" >No </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2. text</td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="B" >Yes     </label><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="C" >No </label></td>
            </tr>
```

I have saved in localstorage the form name ('X'), the input type (radio), the input name ('q1'), and the input value ('B') for example, and I am trying to ensure that on a page refresh the form is repopulated so the user doesn't lose their input. So far I have the following code to to set the radio buttons to checked but I keep getting a 'is not a function' error:

```
function populateFormInput(key, val) {
    var keyParts = key.split('|');
    var inputForm = keyParts[0];
    var inputType = keyParts[1];
    var inputName = keyParts[2];

    if (inputType === 'radio') {
        $('form[name="inputForm"] input[name="inputName"][value="val"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

I can't edit much of the html, though I could give the form an ID if that would help things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of the code you provided will generate that error, however this works for setting the prop: `$('form[name="X"] input[name="q1"][value="B"]').prop('checked', true);` Note there is NO space between the input name and value brackets because a space implies child.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to get past the error (i didn't have a $, sorry should have mentioned)
I have tried it as you suggested and it works fine! Is there anyway to make it work using variable names rather than inputting the values directly? I want to have it in a loop to populate many items at a time and I don't want to write that out for every question (there are 1000's of questions in total)

Comment: Thank you so much imvain2 - Problem solved, you're a star!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables into the selector like follows:

```
$('form[name="' + form_name + '"] input[name="' + field_name + '"][value="' + field_value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You can change the variable names around to fit your loop, but this will point you into the right directions.